# How do I change the font for a SwiftUI Textfiled

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I want to change the format, color, for font-style of the input font shown inside textfields as a user enters their information..

I assume this would be a modifier to the TextField view itself?

Thank you

```
struct ContentView: View {

   @State var email = ""

   var body: some View {
    TextField("email", text: $email)
    //apply modifier here??? 
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your views to follow a style-guide in your app, you could define `viewModifier` and `extension` like this.

```
struct Primary: ViewModifier {
    private let font: Font
    private let foregroundColor: Color
    
    init(size: CGFloat, foregroundColor: Color) {
        self.font = .system(size: UIFontMetrics.default.scaledValue(for: size))
        self.foregroundColor = foregroundColor
    }

    init(font: Font, foregroundColor: Color) {
        self.font = font
        self.foregroundColor = foregroundColor
    }

    public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .font(font)
            .foregroundColor(foregroundColor)
    }
}

extension View {
    func primary() -> some View {
        ModifiedContent(content: self, modifier: Primary(font: .system(size: 13, weight: .semibold, design: .default), foregroundColor: .blue))
    }
}
```

And then use it like this

```
struct SomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Description")
            .primary()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, modifiers work on the `TextField`:

```
TextField("email", text: $email)
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .bold, design: .default))
```